# instanceof use for multiple types

Tags: java, integer, instanceof

I am writing a TypeChecker for MiniJava and ExpOp needs to check if both of the entered expressions are of Integer to use plus, minus, times.

How can I write a line of code inside an `if` statement that includes both expressions and checks if both of them are instances of (`instanceof`) `Integer`?

This is what I have now:

```
n.e1.accept(this) n.e2.accept(this) instanceof Integer
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`instanceof` is a binary operator: it can only have **two** operands.

**The best solution** for your problem is Java's boolean AND operator: `&&`.

It can be used to evaluate two boolean expressions: `<boolean_exp1> && <boolean_exp2>`.
Will return `true` if and only if both are `true` at the time of the evaluation.

```
if (n.e1.accept(this) instanceof Integer &&
    n.e2.accept(this) instanceof Integer) {
    ...
}
```

That being said, another possible solution is to cast them both inside a `try`/`catch` block, and when one of them is not an `Integer` a `ClassCastException` will be thrown.

```
try {
   Integer i1 = (Integer) n.e1.accept(this);
   Integer i2 = (Integer) n.e2.accept(this);
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
   // code reached when one of them is not Integer
}
```

But this is not recommended as it is a known anti-pattern called *Programming By Exception*.

We can show you a thousand ways (creating methods, creating classes and using polymorphism) you can do that with one line, but **none of them will be better or clearer than using the `&&` operator**. Anything other than that will make you code more confusing and less maintainable. You don't want that, do you?

Comment: I know I can use this way of doing that, but I want to know if it's possible to only write instanceof Integet once?

Comment: Unfortunatelly not. `instanceof` is a binary operator: it can only two operands.

Answer (score 8):

You can make a utility function that uses the reflection counterpart of `instanceof`, [`Class.isInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
public static boolean allInstanceOf(Class<?> cls, Object... objs) {
    for (Object o : objs) {
        if (!cls.isInstance(o)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You use it [like this](http://ideone.com/5U804H):

```
allInstanceOf(String.class, "aaa", "bbb"); // => true
allInstanceOf(String.class, "aaa", 123); // => false
```

Comment: Isn't this answering a different question -> check if multiple objects are instances of a single class, rather than if an object is an instance of any of multiple classes.

Comment: @cs95 - where in the question are “multiple classes” even mentioned; OP is “I want to know if the values of two expressions are an `Integer`”

Comment: The title is misleading, look at the actual question and the accepted answer

Comment: but also to get the latter behaviour, just take my code and swap the `Class` and `Object` parameters

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a situation where `instanceof` EITHER of the classes will suffice your needs you can use the `||` (logical OR) operator:

```
if (n.e1.accept(this) instanceof Integer ||
n.e2.accept(this) instanceof Boolean) {
...
}
```