# Check if an object is an instance of any one of a list of classes (Android)

Tags: java, android

I've been looking at this for a while, and whilst it's not critical, I was wondering if there is a neat way (1 liner perhaps) that I can use to check if an object is an instance of any of several classes for example, I could do:

```
if(anObject instanceof Pupil){ ... } 
else if(anObject instanceof Teacher) { ... }
```

And so on and so forth. Is there a better way to do this, or is this as good as I'm going to get?

Comment: Do `Pupil` and `Teacher` have a common parent class?

Comment: They both extend the class Person

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981402/instanceof-use-for-multiple-types

Comment: If you're doing different things for `Pupil` and `Teacher` then it can't be a one liner (and most likely means you have a problem with your design).

Comment: @JordiCastilla I did look at this, but unfortunately it is checking if multiple items are of the same class, where as I need this the other way around (one item may be of any ONE class).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a `Collection` of `Class` objects of your choice and...

```
if(myClasses.contains(obj.getClass())) {
   // obj is one of the classes I care about, so do something
}
```

Of course if you intend to cast `obj` afterwards, this won't help (but that would be, as I said in my comment, an indication of a design problem).

Comment: That's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. My example was a little misleading, as the same thing would have occurred for both Pupil and Teacher in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Through the use of reflection, java/android has a method `isAssignableFrom()` which allow you to test if a particular `Class` object can be assigned from another. Using this fact, you could place your list of test classes into a `Class[]` and check each and every one through a for loop, as follows:

```
public static boolean assignableFrom(Class test, Class[] candidates){
    for(Class candidate : candidates){
        if(candidate.isAssignableFrom(test)){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

in this case, the class under test can be checked against multiple classes for both **equivalence** and **inheritance**, meaning that the method will return `true` even if one of the candidate classes is a superclass of the test class.

If you want instance level relationship only, consider constructing a HashSet of your candidate classes and check if your test object's class in contained within this HashSet (since this gives better performance than a iterative lookup).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you only need to check the exact class of the object and not superclasses, then you could have a list of the classes you want to check for, and simply check if that list contains the class you have.

Here's some code...

```
//Set up list of classes
private static final List<Class> CLASSES = Arrays.asList(new Class[] { String.class, Double.class });
```

Then subsequently when you want to check, it's a one liner...

```
if(CLASSES.contains(anObject.getClass())) { ... }
```