# Check if Object is an instance of a class from a list of classes and cast

Tags: java

I have a number of classes that my object might be at run time. Currently to check which class it is i have a number of if statements like

```
    int id = 0;
    if (object instanceof Comment) {
        id = ((Comment) object).getId();
    }
    if (object instanceof Follow) {
        id = ((Follow) object).getId();
    }
    if (object instanceof Like) {
        id = ((Like) object).getId();
    }
    if (object instanceof Post) {
        id = ((Post) object).getId();
    }
    if (object instanceof User) {
        id = ((User) object).getId();
    }
```

This works but doesn't feel very clean. I had a look at [Check if an object is an instance of any one of a list of classes (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885818/check-if-an-object-is-an-instance-of-any-one-of-a-list-of-classes-android) which suggests a way to check if the object is an instance of a class from a list of classes like

```
if(myClasses.contains(obj.getClass())) {
   // obj is one of the classes I care about, so do something
}
```

However this doesn't then work as i need to go on and cast the object to that class.

Does anyone know of a cleaner way to bot check my object type is of a class from a list of classes AND then cast the object to that class.

Something like

```
if(myClasses.contains(object.getClass())) {
   ((CLASS_THAT_MATCHED) object).getId()
}
```

*NOTE* of course normally I would just make all of the Classes be subclasses of a super class that had the getID method and other methods I need. However in this specific instance these classes all need to be subclasses of a libraries class. Making them inherit from one base classes breaks code in the library. Which i know is a bad design issue on the libraries side but isn't something i can fix.

Comment: what's the type of object variable? how did you declare it? anyway, I see you have the getId() method for each one of the classes. It could be useful to create a parent abstract class, that has the getId() method, and make all the other classes inherit from the abstract one. it would lead you to a simple, only cast: ((MyAbstractClass) object).getId()

Comment: This is what interfaces are for. Make them all implement an interface with a `getId()` method. Interfaces do not constrain your class hierarchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However in this specific instance these classes all need to be subclasses of a libraries class

Then you should use an `interface`:

```
public interface HasId{
   int /* or whatever type is the ID*/ getId();
}

public class Like extends LibrarySuperClass implements HasId{
   ...
}
```

However, if `Like`, `Post` etc are also library classes, you can do something like this:

```
// UNTESTED

Object obj =...;
List list = List.of(
  Like.class,
  Follow.class,
  Comment.class,
  User.class,
  Post.class,
);
Integer id = list
  .stream()
  .filter(class -> class.isInstance(obj))
  .map(class -> (Integer) class.cast(obj).getId())
  .findFirst()
  .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Oof, that last snippet is a disaster. It's got warnings, that `{{}}` style is a very dubious hack (few java programmers know what's going on, making an anonymous subclass has all sorts of issues, but most of all, why is this not `List.add(Like.class, Follow.class, ...)`?? - This answer is much improved if you just stop reading after the first snippet. Perhaps delete the rest?

Comment: @rzwitserloot apart from the `List.add` (that was actually `List.of`), I don't understand what you are saying... what warning are you getting? At most you can say that using reflection is not always the best choice, but already not inheriting from an interface is not the best choice, therefore I don't see the point

Comment: You're using a raw List here, compiling this will generate a warning for using raw types.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use polymorphism. For example, create an interface

```
public interface Message {
    int getId();
}
```

And let your classes implement it. Then you can call the getId method on each of them. Additionally, you can create an abstract class with basic functionality for the Post, Like, etc. classes. Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Re @Alberto Sinigaglia solution,

it works excellent... but looks ridiculous after all necessary casts ;), ex:

```
    ...

    Object obj = new Comment();

    List<?> list = new ArrayList<>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4804401786243829831L;
        {
            add(Comment.class);
            add(Message.class);
            add(Post.class);
        }
    };

    Integer id = (Integer) list.stream().filter(c -> ((Class<?>) c).isInstance(obj))
            .map(c -> (Integer) ((I_ObjectType) ((Class<?>) c).cast(obj)).getObjectId()).findFirst().orElse(null);

    System.out.println("result?=" + id);

    ...
```

each Class implements:

```
public interface I_ObjectType {
    int getObjectId();
}
```